# accessing individual array elements in an array of JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an array of JSON objects - each key has multiple values in an array like this:

```
{
  "1": [
    "hi",
    "hello"
  ]
}
```

How to I access individual elements "hi" and "hello"?

I have tried below but doesn't work

```
//suppose var imdb = [] contains the above array of JSON object
for (var i = 0; i < imdb.length; i++) {
  var object = imdb[i];
  var strArray = JSON.stringify(object, null, 2);
  console.log(strArray) //prints the above
  console.log(imdb[1][0]) // throws error, was expecting to print "hi"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way -

```js
let data = [
  {
  "1": [
    "hi",
    "hello"
    ]
  },

  {
   "2": [
     "hi again",
     "hello again"
    ]
  }
]

function foo(data) {
  data.forEach(obj => {
    for(let prop in obj) {
      obj[prop].forEach(x => console.log(x));
    }
  })
}


foo(data);
```

What this does is -

1. Iterate through the outermost array
2. Get the key for the object (which is the current element of the array being iterated upon)
3. Iterate through the value of this key (which is an array), and print each item.

You can use `JSON.parse()` to get the correct representation of `data` from your original JSON response.

---

For your original code, if you want to print the array values at a specific position, like `"hi"` from the first object, and "hi again" from the second object, here's the modified code -

```
function bar(imdb) {
   // parse imdb first, then -
   for (var i = 0; i < imdb.length; i++) {
     var object = imdb[i];
     var objectKey = Object.keys(object)[0];
     console.log(object[objectKey][0]);
  }
}
```

`Object.keys(object)[0]` would return the key of the current object you're iterating upon (`"1"` or `"2"`), and using `object[objectKey][0]`, you can print the element at the `0`th index of the key's value.